# Set range to all populated cells

Tags: vba, excel, select

I need to set a range to select only the cells in a row which contain data.

Sometimes there will be data in columns B, C, D, E and F of row 3, whilst at other times there will be data in the first 10 or 20 columns of that row.

I've tried the below, but it doesn't work.

```
Dim rRng As Range
Set rRng = Sheets(1).Range("B3").End(xltoright)
```

I know that I'm wide of the mark, but am struggling with this.

This code will be run for a variety of different datasets; sometimes it needs to select five cells, sometimes ten (if populated).

Comment: Try `Set rRng = Sheets(1).Range(Sheets(1).Range("B3"), Sheets(1).Range("B3").End(xltoright))`.  The code you have will only grab the last populated column in row three.  You need to declare the first and last cells.

Answer (score 1):

Select to the last column or select non blanks

```
Sub SelectLstCol()
    Dim Col As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Col = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rng = Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(3, Col))
    rng.Select    'or whatever you want to do with it
End Sub
Sub NonBlanks()
    Dim Col As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Col = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rng = Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(3, Col)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)
    rng.Select    'or whatever you want to do with it
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a function to be able to reuse it more easily :

```
Sub test_andrew_abbott()

MsgBox Get_Row_Range(5).Address
MsgBox Get_Row_Range(Range("A12").Row).Address

End Sub
```

This will be more robust than with `.End(xlToRight)` :

```
Public Function Get_Row_Range(RowNumber As Long) As Range
Dim wS As Worksheet, _
    rRng As Range
Set wS = Sheets(1)

With wS
    Set rRng = .Range(.Range("A" & RowNumber), _
                    .Cells(RowNumber, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
End With


Set Get_Row_Range = rRng
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to your excel file as a data set, I find it better than other way

[image: code]

Comment: FYI - Link only answers typically get flagged for removal.  Links only last so long.  To make SO relevant long term, you need to put the key components into your post so that it can withstand the test of time where links typically wont.